# Is there an equivalent in Python to matlab's imtransform function?

Tags: python, matlab

[The documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imtransform.html)

I'm trying to convert some matlab code to Python. I'm not sure what it does, but if I understood it correctly, it transforms an image into another, with the pixels in the images being the parameters.

Is there anything equivalent I could use for python in PIL, numpy, whichever library? I assume this must be a complex method so atm I'm not expecting to be able to do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You may check [`scipy.ndimage`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html). Perhaps not exact equivalent function to `imtransform`exists. But general transformation functionality do exists.

Answer (score 0):

The [Python Image Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) has a transform function that takes a matrix. I'm not sure if its exactly equivalent to the Matlab semantics:

> im.transform(size, AFFINE, data) => image
>
> im.transform(size, AFFINE, data, filter) => image
>
> Applies an affine transform to the image, and places the result in a new image with the given size.
>
> Data is a 6-tuple (a, b, c, d, e, f) which contain the first two rows from an affine transform matrix. For each pixel (x, y) in the output image, the new value is taken from a position (a x + b y + c, d x + e y + f) in the input image, rounded to nearest pixel.
>
> This function can be used to scale, translate, rotate, and shear the original image.